# How can an external jQuery templates be loaded

Tags: html, jquery, loading, jquery-templates

I have a large number of jQuery templates taking up space in my `<head>` section ("text/x-jquery-tmpl").  I would like to move these  tags to an external file.  I was hoping I could do something like `<link href="/templates.html" type="section"/>` but I realize that's not what link is meant for, and indeed it doesn't seem to work.

How should I do this? I could look into a loader (might be hard to find an html loader though), but that feels like overkill  Could just be that I have no other choice but to include the tags in my page.

Comment: Why not just copy all the separate template code into one file?

Comment: would be sweet if templates could be fetched as a html resource just like css and image files.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a separate file for each template and then use jQuery's load function and inject each template where you want to use it.
For example:

```
$('body').load("templates/template1.html");
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use the src attribute, like this:

```
<script src="/my/templates.html" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"></script>
```

Comment: it is not working :( also no exception on javascript console